# how to get column handle from key in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider a function

def filterGT(session, stmt, attr, value):

which filters rows with values greater than value on attr. So far I have the following 
code:

```
def filterGT(session, stmt, attr, value):  
    stmt=session.query(stmt).filter(stmt.c.agep>value).subquery()
    return stmt
```

My problem is that I am not able construct handle to the column given its label i.e.
If I pass "agep" as attr I want to filter on stmt.c.agep where agep 
is one of the columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `agep` is an attribute on `stmt.c`, you can get the value by using `getattr(stmt.c, "agep")`.

Comment: Great! I googled quite a bit for this. Would you happen to know the reference  just let me know. Just curious.

Comment: [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) is a built-in python function.